# how to create a multirow table?

Tags: tables

I need to create a multi-row table; I have two rows only in the third column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
   \caption{Example LaTeX Table with \texttt{\textbackslash multirow}}  
   \label{tab:example_multirow}
   \small % text size of table content
   \centering % center the table
   \begin{tabular}{lcr} % alignment of each column data
   \toprule[\heavyrulewidth]\toprule[\heavyrulewidth]
   \textbf{Security Level} & \textbf{Security Mode} & \textbf{Protection} \\ 
   \midrule
   \hline
   0&\multirow{2}{*}{Common g text} & Column g2a \\
                                     & Column g2b \\
\hline
   \bottomrule[\heavyrulewidth] 
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But the result is  not correct: 
[image]

Comment: You are missing a `&`. If "Column g2b" should be in the 3rd column, it needs 2 column separators before it: `& & Column g2b \\ ` . As it is now, TeX thinks the text goes in the second column.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker  thank you very much that is the error it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `&`. If "Column g2b" should be in the 3rd column, it needs 2 column separators before it. As it is now, TeX thinks the text goes in the second column.

Also, you might want to enclose the zero in `\multirow` too, so that it is also centered:

```
[...]
\multirow{2}{*}{0} & \multirow{2}{*}{Common g text} & Column g2a \\
                   &                                & Column g2b \\
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want one of these layouts? The tool here is the `makeecell` package. Note the second solution doesn't require `multirow`. Also, I simplified your code for the top and bottom rules: `\heavyrulewidth` is the default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow, makecell, caption, booktabs}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
   \caption{Example LaTeX Table with \texttt{\textbackslash multirow}}
   \label{tab:example_multirow}
   \small % text size of table content
   \centering % center the table
   \begin{tabular}{lcr} % alignment of each column data
   \toprule\toprule
   \textbf{Security Level} & \textbf{Security Mode} & \textbf{Protection} \\
   \midrule
   \midrule
   0&\multirowcell{2}{Common g tex\\ Column g2b} & Column g2a \\
                                     & \\
    \midrule
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
    \vskip 1cm

   \begin{tabular}{lcr} %
   \toprule\toprule
   \textbf{Security Level} & \textbf{Security Mode} & \textbf{Protection} \\
   \midrule
   \midrule
   0& \makecell{Common g tex\\ Column g2b} & Column g2a \\
    \midrule
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

If you need th have two rows for the  third column, you can use `\makecell`:

```
   \begin{tabular}{lcr} %
   \toprule\toprule
   \textbf{Security Level} & \textbf{Security Mode} & \textbf{Protection} \\
   \midrule
   \midrule
   0& \makecell{Common g tex\\ Column g2b} & \makecell[r]{Column g2a \\ Column geb} \\
    \midrule
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: I need that the 3rd column  contains  two rows that means  Column g2a and Column geb

Comment: Really two rows, or could you use `makecell`, which allows for line breaks in standard cells?